# Domain cannot display existing values when editing through the domain

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, domains

I have set a series of domains for my Feature Class in ArcMap. The domains work well but it's just when the FC is under edit, it does not display the existing value sitting in the database.

Instead it displays a blank or something similar to "keep existing value".

Is there a way for the domain to display what the existing value is, as well as still have the domain function?

Do I need to first allocate to domain values first in order for the values to be read whilst editing?

Comment: Is it because the existing field value isn't in the domain? If this is the case then, no, you can't. Either add the existing values to the domain or don't use a domain.

Comment: Maybe the domains that are set up and integrated with the subtypes are not set solely on the fields directly.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Wetland. The existing field value is in the domain. What you said about the domains being set up and integrated with the sub-types seems right. I don't really know how to do this, I'll have to dig around to find something appropriate.

Comment: So if your domains integrated with subtypes, First you need to select an appropriate subtype for a record, then select a domain integrated with this subtype. Otherwise,you need to create a domain not integrated with a subtype.If a feature class has subtypes, domains must be applied at the subtype level and not at the fields level

Answer (score 1):

If a feature class uses  subtype, domians must be applied at the subtype. Otherwise, you need to remove subtype and use domain at the field level.

If you are using subtype:

1. Right click on the feature class and click properties.
2. Go to "Subtypes" tab.
3. Select subtype code(The below image is an example).

[image]

4. At "Default values and domains" , select your field and integrate it with a domain.

[image]

Now you can use and see domain values in attribute table.

Comment: Thanks Wetlands. I think this seems like the solution. I think I understand that the domain must be associated with the subtype for the existing field to be displayed when editing the data. Did you have an example of this, where the default data is displayed in the field and the domain function is still available? A screen shot would be appreciated. I still have some questions around subtypes, it appears that you can only use long and short integers for them ?

Comment: @Dan Shek if my question solved your issue please marked it as correct answer.